# $Failed in the mathematica interface

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

Recently, I bought an Asus Zephyrus G14 and I install Manjaro on it (the gnome version). I made a fresh install of Manjaro and I follow this [reddit guide](https://www.reddit.com/r/ZephyrusG14/comments/ioi9u4/arch_linux_on_zephyrus_g14_guide/).

Anyways the problem is Mathematica interface.
Here what happens when I run Mathematica.

Interface $Failed everywhere
[image: Interface $Failed everywhere]

Blur suggestions
[image: Blur suggestions]

$Failed Again
[image: $Failed Again]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same problem. Apparently is a problem with Mathematica compatibility with High DPI screens.

You have to open the "Option Inspector.." menu:
[Option Inspector Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WO4jw.png)

And search for "ScreenResolutionCompatibilityMode" (without quotations), change the value for "True". By the way, first you need to change the option environment to "Global Preferences", see [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lViDL.png). Then apply changes and restart Mathematica for sure.

Finally, the $Failed disappear. However the Blur problem keep existing. For that I recommend you to search for Magnification configuration in Mathematica or fonts size based on resolution also for Mathematica. I will try a solution using QT_SCALE environment variable but I did't test it yet. Sucesses for you

Comment: Hey, I found a solution that doesn't require ScreenResolutionCompatibilityMode (enabling this was causing issues with plots having poor quality). The answer is here https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/267261/44266